# UICollectionView to read from left to right with multiple rows

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I am creating a `UICollectionView` that has paging enabled and scrolls from left to right. I am using an NSFetchedResultsController to retrieve results from CoreData, which means it uses collection view sections rather than rows. The collection view has 2 rows and therefore appears like the following screenshot (where the order goes top row, bottom row, top row, bottom row etc):

[image]

However, I need the collection view to read from left to right like the following 2 screen shots:

[image]
[image]

Could you please advise on how I would do this in Swift?

Comment: so b has IndexPath(row: 1, section: 0) ?

Comment: @marosoaie I've edited my question with more information. But basically I'm using an NSFetchedResultsController which uses collection view sections.

Comment: then maybe you need to sort your data so that it matches the order you want to achieve?

Comment: iirc the flow layout makes the cells go from left to right, and when there's no more room the next row starts, and so on, so you can only get it the way you want by setting a sort descriptor on your fetch request

Comment: Can you use instead of a,b,c,d,e,f,g etc... rather IndexPath values how you would like to have it ? Also is the last screenshot the preview of page 2 ?

Answer (score 2):

What I would do is this:

1) Sort your data the same way you do it now so that your collection view would look like this:

```
---------
|0|2|4|6|
---------
|1|3|5|7|
---------
```

2) In your `cellForIndexPath` method of your collection view data source return the correct element so that your collection view turns into this:

```
---------
|0|1|2|3|
---------
|4|5|6|7|
---------
```

To do that you can use this logic:

```
public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    var elementIndex: Int!
    if indexPath.row % 2 == 0 {
        // 0 / 2 = 0
        // 2 / 2 = 1
        // 4 / 2 = 2, etc
        elementIndex = indexPath.row / 2
    }
    else {
        // (1 / 2) + round(8.0 / 2.0) = 4
        // (3 / 2) + round(8.0 / 2.0) = 5
        // (5 / 2) + round(8.0 / 2.0) = 6, etc
        elementIndex = (indexPath.row / 2) + Int(round(Double(elements.count) / 2.0))
    }

    // Dequeue your cell
    // let cell = ...

    cell.element = elements[elementIndex]
    return cell
}
```

Basically this should return your elements in the correct order.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. Your 2nd solution half works, the only problem is that I have multiple pages in the collection view, and making the changes above, the collection view now reads like 0-1-2-3     4-5-6-7    8-9-10-11 on the top row, and 12-13-14-15    16-17-18-19     20-21-22-23 on the bottom row

Comment: Oh! I just realized: you want to go 0-1-2-3 on the 1st row of 1st page, then 4-5-6-7 on the 2nd row of the 1st page, and then do the same for the 2nd page: 8-9-10-11 on the 1st row and 12-13-14-15 on the 2nd row of the 2nd page... Is this right? If so, yes, my solution does not do that :(

Comment: Yes that is the way I need it read! Ah no worries, thanks for your help!

Comment: hi @AdamAltinkaya, did your question already answered?, can you share it too? because i'm having the same scenario

Answer (score 0):

First, I think it could help if you provide an example how your cells are sectioned currently (e.g. *section 0: a, b, c, d*, *section 1: e, f*, ...) and how you want the different sections to be displayed/layouted.

---

I'd suggest to create a custom UICollectionViewLayout subclass.

In the prepareLayout method you should calculate and cache the UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes for each cell.

Create variables:

```
let xOffset = 0.0 // leftContentInset within collectionView.bounds
let yOffsetRow0 = 0.0  // y offset of first row within collectionView.bounds
let yOffsetRow1 = 50.0 // y offset of second row within collectionView.bounds
var currentXOffset : CGFloat = xOffset
var currentPage : Int = 0
```

1. calculate the frames until first row is filled to right screen edge (`CGRect(currentXOffset, yOffsetRow0, cellWidth, cellHeight)`, increase currentXOffset)
2. reset `currentXOffset = xOffset`
3. repeat 1. with yOffsetRow1 for second row
4. increment `currentPage += 1`
5. reset `currentXOffset = xOffset + (collectionView.frame.width * currentPage)` // for next page
6. repeat steps 1-5 until layout for all cells is calculated

Answer (score 0):

As you said, you need
1. Paging enabled
2. Scrolling from left to right
3. Multiple sections.

It's a little bit confusing what exactly you want to design. It will be much better if can share proper UI screenshot.

As I understand your problem.

```
let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
    let cv = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
```

Check have you assign the horizontal layout to your collectionView.